# Loosing a Column Value when Shiny executes my function - R

Tags: r

I have already composed a function that runs on shiny, when i run the function locally goes ok, but when run on shiny, the output only shows one of the two columns of the DF.

Data Frame on Rstudio,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kidOs.png)

################################################################

```
library(shiny)
source("LlamadaFunction.R", local = TRUE)
# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output, session){
  table_FF <- reactive({data.frame(ImpresionPliegos(n_copias =input$des_copias, costes_arranque=input$des_Costes_Arranque, ancho=input$des_ancho_formato, alto=input$des_alto_formato, porcentaje_tinta=100, 
                                                                   Destino=input$destiny, papel=input$DES_PAPEL, caras=input$des_Caras, color=input$DES_COLOR, plastificado=input$des_plastificado, 
                                                                   caras_plastificadas=input$des_Caras_plasti, hendido=input$des_hendido, plegado=input$des_plegado, esquinas=input$des_esquinas, 
                                                                   agujeros=input$des_agujeros, troquelado = input$des_troquelado, beneficio=input$des_beneficio, peso=input$des_peso, n_paquetes=input$des_paquetes))})
    plots.dfs <- eventReactive(input$button, {return(list(table_FF()))})
    output$table1  <- renderTable({ plots.dfs()[[1]] })
}

#
# This is the user-interface definition of a Shiny web application. You can
# run the application by clicking 'Run App' above.
#
# Find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
#
#    http://shiny.rstudio.com/
#
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library("DBI")
library("RMySQL")
driver=dbDriver("MySQL");
conexion = dbConnect(driver,host="localhost",dbname="SQL_LOCAL_MAD20",user="root",pass="Guindalera00!!##?",port=3306);

##TABLAS PRINCIPALES
troquelado = dbSendQuery(conexion, "select * from SQL_LOCAL_MAD20.MIS_COSTES_TROQUELADO")
fetch
data_troquelado = fetch(troquelado, n=-1)

hendido = dbSendQuery(conexion, "select * from SQL_LOCAL_MAD20.MIS_COSTES_HENDIDO")
fetch
data_hendido = fetch(hendido, n=-1)

plastificado = dbSendQuery(conexion, "select * from SQL_LOCAL_MAD20.MIS_COSTES_PLASTIFICADO")
fetch
data_plastificado = fetch(plastificado, n=-1)

color = dbSendQuery(conexion, "select * from SQL_LOCAL_MAD20.MIS_COSTES_COLOR")
fetch
data_color = fetch(color, n=-1)

tinta = dbSendQuery(conexion, "select * from SQL_LOCAL_MAD20.MIS_COSTES_TINTA")
fetch
data_tinta = fetch(tinta, n=-1)

vinilo = dbSendQuery(conexion, "select * from SQL_LOCAL_MAD20.MIS_COSTES_VINILO")
fetch
data_vinilo = fetch(vinilo, n=-1)

papel = dbSendQuery(conexion, "select * from SQL_LOCAL_MAD20.MIS_COSTES_PAPEL")
fetch
data_papel = fetch(papel, n=-1)

envio = dbSendQuery(conexion, "select * from SQL_LOCAL_MAD20.MIS_COSTES_ENVIO")
fetch
data_envio = fetch(envio, n=-1)


# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
shinyUI(fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Quinteral PVP APP"),
    numericInput("des_copias", 
                 label = "Numero de copias minimo",
                 value = 1, max=10000000, step=100),
    selectInput("DES_PAPEL", 
                label = "Escoja un tipo de Papel",
                choices = data_papel$DES_PAPEL,
                selected = "Estucado brillo 150"),
    numericInput("des_Caras", 
                label = "Numero de Caras",
                value = 1, max=2, step=1),
    numericInput("des_Caras_plasti", 
                 label = "Numero de Caras plastificadas",
                 value = 1, max=2, step=1),
    numericInput("des_Costes_Arranque", 
                 label = "Costes de Arranque",
                 value = 0, max=100000),
    numericInput("des_ancho_formato", 
                 label = "Formato de Ancho. MAX 32",
                 value = 10, max=32),
    numericInput("des_alto_formato", 
                 label = "Formato de Alto. MAX 45",
                 value = 10, max=45),
    selectInput("DES_COLOR", 
                label = "Escoja el Color de Impresion",
                choices = data_color$DES_COLOR,
                selected = "Color Blanco y Negro  1"),
    selectInput("des_plastificado", 
                label = "Escoja el tipo de plastificado",
                choices = data_plastificado$DES_PLASTIFICADO,
                selected = "NA"),
    selectInput("des_hendido", 
                label = "Escoja el tipo de hendido, si aplica, ",
                choices = c("HENDIDO","NA"),
                selected = "NA"),
    selectInput("des_plegado", 
                label = "Escoja el tipo de plegado, si aplica,",
                choices = c("PLEGADO","NA"),
                selected = "NA"),
    selectInput("des_esquinas", 
                label = "Escoja el tipo de Esquinas, si aplica, ",
                choices = c("ESQUINAS", "NA"),
                selected = "NA"),
    selectInput("des_agujeros", 
                label = "Escoja si conlleva agujeros, si aplica, ",
                choices = c("AGUJEROS", "NA"),
                selected = "NA"),
    selectInput("des_troquelado", 
                label = "Escoja el tipo de troquelado",
                choices = data_troquelado$DES_TROQUELADO,
                selected = "Troquelado 10"),
    selectInput("destiny", 
                label = "Seleccione el Destino del Envio: (P -> PENINSULA, B -> BALEARES, C -> CANARIAS, E -> EUROPA",
                choices = data_envio$COD_DESTINO),
    numericInput("des_peso", 
                 label = "Peso Final Conjunto",
                 value = 1, max=50),
    numericInput("des_paquetes", 
                 label = "Seleccione en cuantos paquetes desea que vaya el envio",
                 value = 1, max=20),
    numericInput("des_beneficio", 
                 label = "Seleccione que % de Beneficio desea obtener.",
                 value = 1, max=1000),
    sidebarPanel(
        actionButton("button", label="Clikea sobre el boton")
    ),
    mainPanel(
        tableOutput("table1")
        )
    
    
))

ImpresionPliegos <- function(n_copias =100, costes_arranque=1000, ancho=10, alto=10, porcentaje_tinta=100, 
                             Destino='P', papel='Estucado brillo 150', caras=1, color='Color Completo 1', plastificado='Plastificado mate por cara', 
                             caras_plastificadas=1, hendido='HENDIDO', plegado='PLEGADO', esquinas='ESQUINAS', 
                             agujeros='AGUJEROS', troquelado = 'Troquelado 10', beneficio=0.33, peso=10, n_paquetes=2) {
  #se calcula el modelo para el numero de copias originles, mas otros posibles escenarios.
  copias_vector = c(n_copias, n_copias*2.5, n_copias*5, n_copias*10)
  #se calcula el ancho real y el largo real, por que hay que respetar los margenes de impresion y los cortes
  ancho_real = ancho + 0.05
  alto_real = alto + 0.05
  #ya podemos sabes cuantas uds caben por pliego.
  uds_pliego = round(32/ancho_real, 0) * round(45/alto_real, 0)
  #calculamos los costes unitarios
  coste_papel_unit_df=subset(data_papel, DES_PAPEL == papel)
  coste_papel_unit = coste_papel_unit_df$COSTE_UNIT
  coste_color_unit_df=subset(data_color, DES_COLOR == color)
  coste_color_unit = coste_color_unit_df$COSTE_UNIT
  coste_plastificado_unit_df=subset(data_plastificado, DES_PLASTIFICADO == plastificado)
  coste_plastificado_unit = coste_plastificado_unit_df$COSTE_UNIT
  coste_hendido_unit_df=subset(data_hendido, COD_HENDIDO == hendido)
  coste_hendido_unit = coste_hendido_unit_df$COSTE_UNIT
  coste_plegado_unit_df=subset(data_hendido, COD_HENDIDO == plegado)
  coste_plegado_unit = coste_plegado_unit_df$COSTE_UNIT
  coste_esquinas_unit_df=subset(data_hendido, COD_HENDIDO == esquinas)
  coste_esquinas_unit = coste_esquinas_unit_df$COSTE_UNIT
  coste_agujeros_unit_df=subset(data_hendido, COD_HENDIDO == agujeros)
  coste_agujeros_unit = coste_agujeros_unit_df$COSTE_UNIT
  coste_troquelado_unit_df=subset(data_troquelado, DES_TROQUELADO == troquelado)
  coste_troquelado_unit = coste_troquelado_unit_df$COSTE_UNIT
  total_pliegos= trunc(copias_vector/uds_pliego) + 4 #siempre se necesitan 3 pliegos de margen + 1 de redondeo hacia arriba
  #Coste de Papel
  Coste_Papel = coste_papel_unit*total_pliegos
  Coste_impresion = coste_color_unit*total_pliegos*caras
  Coste_plastificado = coste_plastificado_unit*total_pliegos*caras_plastificadas
  Coste_troquelado=coste_troquelado_unit*total_pliegos
  millares = round(total_pliegos/1000, 0)+1
  Coste_hendido_full_unit=coste_hendido_unit+coste_plegado_unit+coste_esquinas_unit+coste_agujeros_unit
  coste_hendido_full = Coste_hendido_full_unit*millares
  Coste_final_unit=Coste_Papel+Coste_impresion+Coste_plastificado+Coste_troquelado+coste_hendido_full
  #Costes de envio
  paks = n_paquetes
  kg_finales = peso
  peso_medio=round(kg_finales/paks, 0)
  coste_unit_kg_envio = subset(data_envio, COD_DESTINO==Destino & NUM_PESO == peso_medio)
  peso_x=coste_unit_kg_envio$NUM_PESO
  kgs_adicionales <- ifelse(peso_medio - peso_x <=0, 0, round(peso_medio - peso_x, 0))
  coste_unit_envio_final<-coste_unit_kg_envio$COSTE_ENVIO
  coste_adic_final<-coste_unit_kg_envio$COSTE_ADICIONAL_KG
  costes_envio=coste_unit_envio_final*peso_x + kgs_adicionales*coste_adic_final
  ###
  bf<- beneficio
  CF <- costes_arranque+costes_envio
  pvp=(Coste_final_unit+CF) * (1+bf)
  table33 <- as.data.frame(cbind(copias_vector, pvp), c("COPIAS","PVP"))
  return(table33)
}
```

Comment: The code is pointing to a localhost database though.Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: Are you using separate files for the server and ui? You've pasted in the function `ImpresionPliegos()` after the UI, but presumably this isn't where it is actually defined in your code. I think it's going to matter where exactly it is defined, and this is why you really need to give a reproducible example.